# BootCamp The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned even if it does

Tags: bootcamp, disk-space

So, I'm trying to install windows 10 through bootcamp and I have this problem:

[image: Bootcamp]

when I check for free space I see this:

[image: Disk Util]

Even if I free a couple of more gb the error remains the same. I turned of Time Machine and deleted all the cache. I see there are similar questions but none of the solutions has worked for me (usually deleting tm, cache or actually seeing that there was less free space).

Comment: You do realize that you can not add additional space to the Windows after you install. So, trying to install using the minimum amount of space will probably leave you will little space for installing additional programs and storing your user files.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'm not trying to add space to windows after the installation but to install it